# Add a maximum number of days with react-dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a maximum number of days to pick using react-dates.
Basically the inverse of **minimumNights** property that already exists.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `isOutsideRange` predicate prop.
You pass in a function that will set each date as available or not respectively to your maximum number of days variable.

Example:

```
const maximumDays = 6;
isOutsideRange = day => (
        focusedInput === END_DATE && (day.isBefore(startDate) || day.isAfter(startDate.clone().add(maximumDays, 'days')))
      );
```

And then pass it to the component:

```
<DateRangePicker
  isOutsideRange={isOutsideRange}
  onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
  onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
  focusedInput={focusedInput}
  startDate={startDate}
  endDate={endDate}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fromRange = '29/03/2019';
let toRange = '30/04/2019';
const isOutsideRange = (day => {
    let dayIsBlocked = false;     
     if(day > moment(fromRange)) {
        dayIsBlocked = true;
    }     
    if(day > moment(toRange)) {
        dayIsBlocked = true;
    }    
    return dayIsBlocked;
})
```